# clojure performance on badly performing code

Tags: clojure

I have completed [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery) problem on hackerrank and my solution passes most test cases but it is not fast enough for 4 out of the 11 test cases.

My solution looks like this:

```
(ns scratch.core
  (require [clojure.string :as str :only (split-lines join split)]))

(defn ascii [char]
  (int (.charAt (str char) 0)))

(defn process [text]
  (let [parts (split-at (int (Math/floor (/ (count text) 2))) text)
        left (first parts)
        right (if (> (count (last parts)) (count (first parts)))
                (rest (last parts))
                (last parts))]

    (reduce (fn [acc i]
              (let [a (ascii (nth left i))
                    b (ascii (nth (reverse right) i))]
                (if (> a b)
                  (+ acc (- a b))
                  (+ acc (- b a))))
              ) 0 (range (count left)))))

(defn print-result [[x & xs]]
  (prn x)
  (if (seq xs)
    (recur xs)))

(let [input (slurp "/Users/paulcowan/Downloads/input10.txt")
      inputs (str/split-lines input)
      length (read-string (first inputs))
      texts (rest inputs)]
  (time (print-result (map process texts))))
```

Can anyone give me any advice about what I should look at to make this faster?

Would using recursion instead of reduce be faster or maybe this line is expensive:

```
right (if (> (count (last parts)) (count (first parts)))
                (rest (last parts))
                (last parts))
```

Because I am getting a count twice.

Comment: `(int (.charAt (str char) 0))` is the same as `(int char)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redundantly calling reverse on every iteration of the reduce:

```
user=> (let [c [1 2 3]
             noisey-reverse #(doto (reverse %) println)]
         (reduce (fn [acc e] (conj acc (noisey-reverse c) e))
                 []
                 [:a :b :c]))
(3 2 1)
(3 2 1)
(3 2 1)
[(3 2 1) :a (3 2 1) :b (3 2 1) :c]
```

The reversed value could be calculated inside the containing let, and would then only need to be calculated once.

Also, due to the way your `parts` is defined, you are doing linear time lookups with each call to `nth`. It would be better to put parts in a vector and do indexed lookup. In fact you wouldn't need a reversed parts, and could do arithmetic based on the count of the vector to find the item to look up.